# Sqlserver cannot write large text to excelfile with ACE, using IMEX=1, result=object is read-only

Tags: sql-server-2012, excel

I have a table Test with column id (int) and column label (varchar(512)) and an excelfile test.xlsx with sheet test and the two columns. I use the ACE-provider to write from sqlserver to the excelfile. There are values longer than 255 characters in the column "label".

### Scenario 1

IMEX=0, no values longer than 255 characters; I trunc label to 255 characters

```
insert into OPENROWSET(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0 Xml;Database=D:\test\test.xlsx;HDR=NO;IMEX=0;ReadOnly=FALSE',
    'SELECT * FROM [test$]')
SELECT id,
       cast(label as varchar(255)) label
FROM   Test
```

This works fine.

### Scenario 2

IMEX=0, values longer than 255 characters

```
insert into OPENROWSET(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0 Xml;Database=D:\test\test.xlsx;HDR=NO;IMEX=0;ReadOnly=FALSE',
    'SELECT * FROM [test$]')
SELECT id,
       label
FROM   Test
```

Since there are values longer then 255 characters in label I get the message

> String or binary data would be truncated.

This is normal for IMEX=0.

### Scenario 3

IMEX=1, no values longer than 255 characters

```
insert into OPENROWSET(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0 Xml;Database=D:\test\test.xlsx;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;ReadOnly=FALSE',
    'SELECT * FROM [test$]')
SELECT id,
       cast(label as varchar(255)) label
FROM   Test
```

I get this message:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"
>   returned message "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.".
>   Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 The OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an
>   error. The provider indicates that the user did not have the
>   permission to perform the operation. Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line
>   5 The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server
>   "(null)" could not INSERT INTO table "[Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0]".

### Scenario 4

IMEX=1, values longer than 255 characters

```
insert into OPENROWSET(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0 Xml;Database=D:\test\test.xlsx;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;ReadOnly=FALSE',
    'SELECT * FROM [test$]')
SELECT id,
       label
FROM   Test
```

I get the same message:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"
>   returned message "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only."
>   etc.

---

Now I made sure the excel-file has all the persmission for the users (sqlserver-service-user, user running the script, ...) involved (otherwise it wouldn't write any lines in the very first scenario with imex=0), I even tried with "everyone", no succes.

My guess is, if IMEX=1 is involved, there is another folder or file that needs acces?

Note that I already gave read/write permission to the user running the query on "C:\Users\userThatRunsServiceOfSqlServer\AppData\Local\Temp".

Any suggestions?

Sql server 2012 sp3 / Excel 2010

Comment: have you tried to write to the excel file using the import/export wizard?

Comment: James, I used SSMS, and Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is in the provider-list of the linked servers. But, as I tried the import-wizard (directly on the server), I can choose excel 2007, but then I get an error:The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)

Comment: so the ace provider has been installed for 64 bits (with Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable) I guess, and the import/export tool of ssms itself is 32bit, But this has nothing to do with my initial problem, no? or does it?

Comment: Maaaybe. These drivers can be a bitch. In the SQL Server Export wizard, when you choose a destination, what do you see? I've got 3 that might work on my end: Microsoft Access (microsoft Access Database Engine), Microsoft Access (Microsoft Jet Database Engine) and Microsoft Excel. I always use the 3rd one, since the other two argue with me so much!

Comment: I have the last two options, and I also choose excel. Well thanks anyway (if i have to use the export wizard, I will install the 32 bit version of the ace provider, but openrowset in my ssms-query uses the 64bit version and that one is installed)